# Distributed relational data fast query interface

Tags: database, architecture, reporting

I have a system consisting of highly relational data distributed between Oracle DB and PostgreSQL tables (and some MySQL too).
I need to build a reporting systems that breaks down and filters through those records, so I'm considering using a data warehouse or a NoSQL database to hold an aggregated version of those records.

Can you recommend a software / data store to begin with?

Example:

```
Name -> Oracle Users table
Gender -> Oracle Users_Extension table
Country -> Oracle contacts table
User items -> Postgres User_items table
Item insertion date -> Postgres User_items table
```

as sample query might be:

get the count of user items, broken down by country, where the gender is female over a month period.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a data warehouse it's a good option if you plan to have more reporting than data updating or you don't need reports with real time data, the reason is that a data warehouse is just an snapshot of the data at the time you syncronized the databases and often, you can only do so once or twice a day.

If you need real time data, your best option is to use a reporting/BI tool that can connect and make reports from different databases, like [DBxtra](http://dbxtra.com/), where you just create the data connections, drag and drop the tables into a common (SQL) query, design a pretty report and let your users see it in a web browser.